# How to switch back to old cluster in rabbitmq incase of the system or hostname changes?

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

Due to some problems we changed server name and after doing this we restarted server. We found that rabbitmq service stopped and we started rabbitmq service but we lost total data related to rabbitmq and it is looking like we setup new one and cluster name also changed to new server name. Now i want to switch back to my old cluster or i want to retrieve old data. We are using windows server 2012. How to do this?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Windows sever 2012

Answer (score 1):

RabbitMQ by default, stores the data inside an directory based on hostname.

The default dir in widows is:

```
C:\Users\{youruser}\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\db
```

In my case for example is:

```
C:\Users\gabriele\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\db\rabbit@windowsdev-mnesia
```

and

```
C:\Users\gabriele\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\db\rabbit@windowsdev-plugins-expand
```

Now you should have 2 directories inside `C:\Users\{youruser}\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\db` with old-hostname and new-hostname.

You can:

1. stop rabbitmq
2. backup your old-hostname directory
3. delete the new-hostname directory
4. rename the old-hostname directory with the new-hostname

I think that you still have your data in your server.

LEt me know.

Comment: As there was no time in experimenting this solution, we asked to team to revert the host name to old host name. After changing the host name i have restarted the rabbitmq server then it worked. I think your solution will work.